# In a .Net 5 Core web app, Is there a way I can persist logged in user's sessions after recicling of AppPool?

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, razor-pages, .net-5

I have a web app that executes in different servers with very different specifications, it depends on demand and on clients budget sometimes. Users are made aware of the downgraded experience of running the app on a server with very low RAM for example.

This year we updated our code from a ASP.Net 4.6 monolithic MVC5 code base to ASP.Net Core 3.1 Razor Pages using a Clean Architecture, and more recently to .Net 5. We have everything running smooth and as expected we experienced a huge performance boost.

The only problem we're facing is in scenarios with very low RAM shared hosting were the app has to be executed "out of process" and the app pool keeps restarting after very little time, active users get logged out on every app pool recycling. This didn't happened on the old version of the app, user would experience a delay on their request (sometime a rather long one but users working under this scenarios were aware of their server limitations), but after the app was up they could continue working without having to log in again. Now, after every app pool recycling all users sessions expire and they are asked to log in again, this is understandably unacceptable from their part. I didn't expect this to happen because we're using default identity, authentication and authorization which as far as I understand is cookie based.

One thing that I find odd is that on the site that keeps logging users out there are only two Cookies after users log in.
[image: Only two cookies]

While on other sites where normal behavior is shown there are four cookies.
[image: Four cookies]

I am aware that this is not the best scenario to run a web server, but sometimes that's all there is.

Is there any way I can persist user sessions (maybe in SQL Server) so I can achieve something similar to what we had before? Or am I barking at the wrong tree here?

Comment: You might need to try this way https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/configure-sql-server-session-state-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: @4d875752c6a784cb21d90a2818c6e0 that article was already obsolete when it was published - it mentions `project.json` and `dnxcore50`. Session storage is very well documented in the docs, and doesn't work the same way it did in .NET Core 1.0

Comment: In all web applications, both .NET Old and .NET Core, persistent session storage is used not only to persist values across recycles, but to allow web farms to use a consistent state for the same user, no matter which web server processes a request. For .NET Core 2.x and later, [session storage can be configured](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-5.0#configure-session-state) to be either in-memory or distributed through the IDistributedCache interface and implementations. The docs show how to configure sessions and caching

Comment: The [Distributed caching in ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-5.0) doc shows how to specify different caching providers, from the default in-memory provider, to Redis, SQL Server or NCache. Other providers are available as NuGet packages too, [like this MySQL provider](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.Extensions.Caching.MySql/). You could even create your own implementation, targeting whatever caching is provided by your hoster. Cloud providers like AWS, Google or Amazon all provide a Redis-compatible cache at least.

Comment: For a specific answer, you'll have to post your code. The question doesn't contain much information, except mentioning it uses sessions and in-memory storage. `This didn't happened on the old version of the app` I doubt it unless all session data was stored on the client as cookies. Without any code, one can only guess. The [Cookies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-5.0#cookies) section in the session management docs explains why depending on cookies is problematic, esp after GDPR

Comment: `I am aware that this is not the best scenario to run a web server, but sometimes that's all there is.` think microservices, AWS Lambda and Serverless. This scenario *enforces* stateless web apps with remote session storage, to allow using a dynamic number of transient web apps/endpoints/services to serve requests